# How to list a parent Model and its child table in an order manner using Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this table named `department` that is having parent/child relationship within itself. A department can have no or many child, my problem now is how can i show in table from a parent followed by its child in an order manner? For example:

```
Parent A
Child A
Child Y
Parent B
Parent C
Child F
Child N
```

I even tried it in sql which is something like this but i have no luck:

```
select d.name from departments d left join departments dd on d.id = dd.parent_id ORDER by d.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel can handle this quite eloquently (pun intended). Simply define a model and 2 relationships:

```
class Department extends Model(){
  public function parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, "parent_id", "id");
  }
  public function children(){
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, "parent_id", "id");
  }
}
```

Then, when querying, initially target those without a parent ("top-level" departments)

```
$departments = Department::doesntHave("parent")->with(["children"])->get();
```

Then, simply loop the `$departments` and their `"children"`:

```
foreach($departments AS $department){
  echo $department->name; 
  foreach($department->children AS $child){
    echo $child->name;
  }
}
```

As these are nested loops, you'll get the correct result; each "top-level" department will be listed immediately followed by 0 to X of its children.

Comment: It should be noted that this only handles two levels. That may well be what OP needs, but it's not likely to scale to match further levels very well - if you need that it may be better to get all the items and sort the returned items by parent in the collection.

Comment: Oh yeah, absolutely, but I was basing this off of the example that only shows a single level. I was gonna make a note of that, but thanks for that. Handling infinite levels of recursion is slightly more complicated, but actually can be done via eloquent. If required, I'll update my question to demonstrate that.

Comment: Thank you very much it just that it breaks my links and server is complaining saying ```Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.```. Since you have mentioned the N level of recursion how should i handled it and in real world what are the scenarios that requires this kind of level?

Comment: Ah, sorry. The `links()` issue means you're using `paginate(X)` instead of `->get()`. You can do this, but it won't quite work as expected, as it will limit the top-level departments to X entries, but not the children. As for real-world examples, there are plenty. Recursive entities exist in a lot of places, like a folder structure; can have infinite depth of sub-folders. It's pretty complicated to handle, as you'll have to recursively traverse the children-of-children, but defining the functions in Laravel is actually pretty simple when you understand how it all works.

Comment: yeah indeed, my mistake. i didn't notice tha change of ```get()``` and ```paginate()```. but it is common to use this level? i mean, once landed in a real world is it day to day basis?

Comment: I've been coding professionally for a little over 6 years, and I personally have only had to handle infinite levels of recursion in Laravel on a handful of occasions. Generally, handling a simple `parent-child` relationship is enough, and it's rare to have to do `parent->child->child->... ad infinitum`, but it does happen, and my experience doesn't necessarily match everyone's. Be prepared for it, but don't necessarily expect it. Cheers!